# No schema panel present in MySQL workbench in Ubuntu

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am using MySQL Workbench Version 8.022 on Ubuntu 20.04 OS. Strangely there is no schema panel present in MySQL workbench window and I can't manage to find a way to display the schema panel.

I have installed the snap edition of MySQL-Workbench-Community

Following is the screenshot -

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be with the snap package I guess. I removed the snap package -

```
sudo snap remove mysql-workbench-community
```

Then I went to the link https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/ to download the MySQL-Workbench-Community for my version of OS.

For me it was `mysql-workbench-community_8.0.26-1ubuntu20.04_amd64.deb`

Then I installed it from the terminal using the command -

```
sudo gdebi mysql-workbench-community_8.0.26-1ubuntu20.04_amd64.deb
```

Now I open MySQL-Workbench -

[image]

As shown in the screenshot, this time I have the Schemas tab to the right side of Administration tab. I click on the Schemas tab -

[image]

As shown in the screenshot, now my Schemas Panel is open.

Answer (score 1):

See where it says "Administration" and then there are left/right arrows either side. Click the right arrow to get to Schemas. Or pull the vertical divider to the right to show both. Took me a while to find it too!

Answer (score 0):

Update: the tab selector for Administration and Schemas is now at the *bottom* of the Navigator window:
[image: Location of Schemas Tab in MySQL Workbench]

Answer (score 0):

Quick way to figure that out is my clicking on the right scroll button of the side bar just below the tool bar, where Administration is.